# is there any way i can extract first n comments from this piece of code?

Tags: php, facebook

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'','secret'=>''
));
$post = "10152390205162139";
$comments = array();
$done = false;
$options = array();
$path = "/".$post.'/comments';
while(!$done){
    try{
        $data = $facebook->api($path,'GET',$options);
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $data = null;
        $done = true;
    }
    if(!is_null($data)){
         $comments = array_merge($comments, $data['data']);
        if(isset($data['paging']['next']) && !empty($data['paging']['next'])){
            $parts = parse_url($data['paging']['next']);
            $path  = $parts['path'];
            parse_str($parts['query'], $options);
        } else {
            $done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is, extract list of comments from the particular post made by a page, now i want to limit the number of comments like 100 or 200, since some of the post's have comments more than 50k, it kills my script :\

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`limit`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) option, so you probably only have to change:

```
$options = array();
```

to:

```
$options = array('limit' => 100);
```

Comment: it worked thanks :) btw are they 1 to 5 or n to n-5 ? curious

Comment: @avinashizhere There is an `offset` option as well, if that's what you mean.

Comment: pretty much yes, it would be great if i can use offset too :)

Comment: @avinashizhere You can, but it might be more interesting to use for example the `since` or `until` options as the pagination could change a lot as comments are added in real-time.

Comment: can u tell me? sice i searched n wasn't successful :(

Comment: @avinashizhere Check the page I linked to, all options and their description are there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51112/discussion-between-avinashizhere-and-jeroen)

Comment: i didn't get the link, where is it?

Comment: @avinashizhere In the answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

You could try limiting the `while` clause in your script, something like:

```
while (!$done || count($comments) <= 200) {
    ...
}
```